# Bootstrap-vue doesn't load CSS webpack app

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, bootstrap-vue

i am writing a vuejs app with bootstrap 4. I followed the documentation and it did work on my local computer project.
but once I installed it on the remote server project ( webpack project : I am new into this kind of projects ) it didnt work, it crashes the whole project (keeps loading).
I added to main.js

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
```

`Vue.use(BootstrapVue);`

I do have both **vue-style-loader** and **css-loader** in `package.json`

I added in my webpack.config **module.rules**

```
{
  test: /\.css/,
  use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader'] // BOTH are needed!
}
```

Yet nothing did change am i missing something ?
any tips for a beginner ?

Comment: Could you please describe in clear what you mean by *"installed it on the remote server project"*? Because what it should mean is: `vue-cli-service build` (on local) + upload `/dist` folder on remote. That's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main.ts` (or `.js`):

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
```

From [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#using-module-bundlers).

---

As an alternative, if you're keen on using `@import` in one of your SCSS files, use:

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
```

or:

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

---

As for *"tips for a beginner"*:

- read docs
- stay safe